# Google Big Query Returning Multiple rows using CurrentTimestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I am querying in google big query to return results based on the `MAX(currentTimestamp)`, though timestamp being different it returns 2 results for few of the id's.

Query

```
select
    ticketId,
    functionalAreaName as fan,
    ticketTypeName as tan,
    currentTicketStatusName as cts,
    lastUpdatedTimestamp,
    currentTimestamp
from 
    General_Report_Data 
where
    ticketId = "4543218762907648" and
    currentTimestamp in (select max(currentTimestamp) 
                         from General_Report_Data d
                         group by d.ticketId) and 
    (createdTimestamp >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and
     createdTimestamp <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

and I'm getting this result:

[Big query result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd8qO.png)

Answer (score 1):

The logic in your subquery which checks the max timestamp value is incorrect.  You intend to find the maximum timestamp for a given ticket, which implies the following query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM General_Report_Data grd
WHERE
    ticketId = "4543218762907648" AND
    currentTimestamp IN (SELECT MAX(currentTimestamp) FROM General_Report_Data d
                         WHERE d.ticketId = grd.ticketId) AND
    createdTimestamp BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

The reason your current attempt gives multiple records is that the subquery returns multiple max timestamps, for more than one ticket.  Note that we could also rewrite your query using an analytic function.

Comment: I tried with the above query but getting the error as "grd.ticketId" not found in table d , but if I replace grd.ticketId with the "4543218762907648" then getting the correct result.Only one result as expected.

Comment: @kaushikdugar You should not be seeing that error, and my answer is ANSI compliant AFAIK.